# Can you theme the iPod classic UI?

Tags: ipod, ui

Can  you theme the 80gb iPod classic so the menus or the music player have a different graphical user interface?

Comment: Theme which bits? The menus? Music player? I'd be surprised either way.

Comment: The Menus or music player

Answer (score 1):

[Ipodwizard](http://www.ipodwizard.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) claims to do what you want and claims to not do any permanent damage.

Comment: that won't work on mine

Comment: oh, why is that?

Comment: You will see from this Wiki entry that the 6th gen model is not supported http://www.ipodwizard.net/wiki/index.php/IPod_Generation#6th_Generation

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for this is no.

iPod Wizzard can change the UI for earlier models but not an 80gb 6th Gen model or upwards. Using these hacks does have its risks and will not always be fully stable.